# Way to see when a user was added to a GCP Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

As the title says is there a way where one can see a timeline or logs when each user was added to a GCP Project? We need it for internal audit purposes.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [Admin activity audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/#admin-activity). They are enabled by default and you can [view them in Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/logging/audit-logging).

Comment: Can you please explain further how I can get them? I can see a bunch of logs.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Stackdriver > Logs Viewer, change the filter to advanced and use something like this:

```
resource.type="project"
protoPayload.request."@type"="type.googleapis.com/google.iam.v1.SetIamPolicyRequest"
```

You will get the changes in the Project Policy that will include new users added.

Comment: I am unable to see new users that have been added. Can you send me a screenshot of how it would look like?